# How to solve the eigenvalue problem $y'' + \lambda y=0$, $y'(-L) = y'(L)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How do I solve the eigenvalue problem $y'' + \lambda y=0$, $y'(-L) = y'(L)=0$?

My attempt:

- Case 1: $\lambda=0$. If $\lambda=0$, then the BVP becomes $y''(x)=0$, $y'(-L)=y'(L)=0$. The general solution to this differential equation is $y(x)=Ax+B$. Taking the derivative gives $y'(x)=A$, and the boundary condition implies that $A=0$, but $B$ can be arbitrary. This means that $\mu_0=0$ must be an eigenvalue and the function
  $$y_0(x)=B,\quad B\text{ is a constant}$$
  is its corresponding eigenfunction.
- Case 2: $\lambda<0$. Let $\lambda = -p^2<0$. The BVP becomes $y''(x)-p^2y(x)=0$, $y'(-L)=y'(L)=0$. The solution to this DE is $y(x)=A\cosh(px)+B\sinh(px)$. Taking the derivative gives $y'(x)=Ap\sinh(px)+Bp\cosh(px)$. Plugging in $-L$ and $L$ gives
  \begin{align*}
      A\cosh(pL) - B\sinh(pL) &= 0\\
      A\cosh(pL) + B\sinh(pL) &= 0
  \end{align*}
  Solving for $A$ and $B$ gives $A=B=0$, which is a trivial solution.
- Case 3: $\lambda>0$. Let $\lambda = p^2 > 0$. The BVP becomes $y''(x)+p^2y(x)=0$, $y'(-L)=y'(L)=0$. The solution to this DE is $y(x)=A\cos(px)+B\sin(px)$. Taking the derivative gives $y'(x)=-Ap\sin(px) + Bp\cos(px)$, and applying the boundary condition,
  \begin{alignat}{3}
      & y'(-a) && = Ap\sin(pL) + Bp\cos(pL) = 0 \quad&& \Longrightarrow\quad A\sin(pL) + B\cos(pL) = 0 \label{eq:X2}\\
      & y'(a) && = -Ap\sin(pL) + Bp\cos(pL) = 0 \quad&& \Longrightarrow\quad A\sin(pL) - B\cos(pL) = 0 \label{eq:Y2}
  \end{alignat}
  Adding the two equations, we obtain $2A\sin(pL)=0$. This implies that either $A=0$ or $\sin(pL)=0$. Subtracting the two equations gives $2B\cos(pL)=0$. This implies that either $B=0$ or $\cos(pL)=0$. To summarize, we have
  $$A=0,\;\text{or}\;\sin(pL)=0,\quad\text{and}\quad B=0\;\text{or}\;\cos(pL)=0.$$
  Together, they form four cases: $A=B=0$, $A=\cos(pL)=0$, and $B=\sin(pL)=0$, and the final one gives $\cos(pL)=\sin(pL)=0$, which is not possible. The second, and third case gives
  $$p_1 = \frac{n\pi}{L}\quad\text{and}\quad p_2 = \frac{(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi}{L},\quad n =1, 2, 3,\ldots,$$
  respectively. Therefore, there are only two non-trivial families of solutions in this case:
  $$\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)\quad\text{and}\quad\sin\left(\frac{(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi}{L}x\right),\quad n=1, 2, 3,\ldots$$
  and thus the corresponding eigenfunctions are
  $$y_n(x)=a_n\cos\left(\sqrt{\lambda_{n, 1}}x\right)+b_n\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda_{n, 2}}x\right)$$
  where
  $$\lambda_{n, 1}=\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2,\quad \lambda_{n, 2}=\left(\frac{(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi}{L}\right)^2$$

Question: Is my solution correct? Should there be two families of eigenvalues like case 3?

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate some cases by proper normalizations. Start by solving
$$
         y''+\lambda y = 0,\;\; y'(-L)=0, y(-L)=1.
$$
Adding the condition $y(-L)=1$ eliminates the trivial solution, and eliminates an ambiguity in the solution by normalizing it at $-L$. The unique solution is
$$
        y_{\lambda}(x)=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}(x+L)).
$$
Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue iff $y_{\lambda}'(L)=0$; so the eigenvalue equation is
$$
           \sqrt{\lambda}\sin(2L\sqrt{\lambda})=0.
$$
Therefore, the eigenvalues are
$$
       \lambda=n^2\pi^2/4L^2,\;\; n=0,1,2,3\cdots.
$$
The corresponding normalized eigenfunction solutions are
$$
    y_0(x)=1,\\   y_n(x)=\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2L}(x+L)\right),\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots .
$$
**Check:** These solutions do satisfy $y_n'(-L)=0,\;y_n'(L)=0$. And they are solutions of $y_n''+\lambda y_n=0$, where $\lambda=n^2\pi^2/4L^2$, as required.